# Spaces in InputBox Cause Multiple Variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

The Code below asks for a input and then it will create a folder with the input name in root directory, but if user enter two words which have space between them, it will create two folders and I want to avoid it, for example if user enter (Good Time) it will create two folders named Good and Time, but I want to get only ONE Folder named "Good Time"
How to fix the code?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

SET _prompt=%1

::Create the VBS script with an echo statement:
ECHO Wscript.Echo Inputbox("Enter %_prompt%","Input Required")>%TEMP%\~input.vbs

:s_GetInput
:: Run the vbScript and save the output
FOR /f "delims=/" %%G IN ('cscript //nologo %TEMP%\~input.vbs') DO set _string=%%G

:: Delete the VBS file
DEL %TEMP%\~input.vbs

mkdir .\%_string%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for spaces in file-/foldernames use doublequotes around:

```
mkdir ".\%_string%"
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, But how to use UNICODE names? it won't work if I type Arabic or Persian words :(

Comment: @Stranger Why don't you just use `set /p _string=Enter %_prompt%:` to get folder name with no vbscript?

Comment: @kul-tigin Unicode support is limited in a cmd prompt too.